# Ayuda con una funcion que valida Letras - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente código que me consegui **(Está en JavaScript)** el cual me valida el ingreso de solamente caractéres; y no números o caractéres especiales; dentro de un **input**:

Codigo:

```
function SoloLetras(e)
{
   key = e.keyCode || e.which;
   tecla = String.fromCharCode(key);
   letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZáéíóúabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
   especiales = "8-37-39-46";

   tecla_especial = false;

   for(var i in especiales){
        if(key == especiales[i]){
            tecla_especial = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(letras.indexOf(tecla)==-1 && !tecla_especial){
        return false;
    }

}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que, además de todo, me permita ingresar espacios en blanco al momento de ir escribiendo. Eso si me pudieran ayudar, estaría muy agradecido.

*PD. El código me funciona, pero le quiero agregar lo ya mencionado.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`especiales` tiene que ser un array para que lo puedas recorrer como pretendes dentro del loop `for`. Simplemente tenés que agregar el `32` que es el código del espacio.

`especiales = [8, 32, 37, 39, 46];`

[Códigos de teclas](http://keycode.info/).

Comment: gracias me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Agregas un listener al texto, y con una regex verificas si cada letra ingresada en el momento en que se escribe cumple la expresion regular, si no uso el metodo preventDefault() para no poder escribir y retorno falso.

```js
function _keyValidation() {
 var text = document.getElementById("area");
 text.addEventListener("keypress", _check);
  function _check(e) {
  var textV = "which" in e ? e.which : e.keyCode,
      char = String.fromCharCode(textV),
      regex = /[a-z]/ig;
      if(!regex.test(char)) e.preventDefault(); return false;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", _keyValidation);
```

```html
<textarea id="area" cols=40 rows=7>

</textarea>
```