# Aceptar sólo letras y acentos en un input con funcion javascript

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

La siguiente funciona correctamente para aceptar en el input solo letras (A a la Z incluyendo la Ñ), las teclas: borrar, izquierda, derecha, arriba, abajo y espacio, **cómo se podrían aceptar tambien los acentos**

```
//FUNCION PARA VALIDAR LETRAS
function sololetras(e) {
    key=e.keyCode || e.which;

    teclado=String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();

    letras="qwertyuiopasdfghjklñzxcvbnm ";

    especiales="8-37-38-46-164-46";

    teclado_especial=false;

    for(var i in especiales){
        if(key==especiales[i]){
            teclado_especial=true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(letras.indexOf(teclado)==-1 && !teclado_especial){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Cabe mencionar que el charset de la pagina esta definido como utf-8

Comment: en letras= agrega las letras con acento

Comment: Muchas gracias @MiguelZarate, esa fue la solución

Comment: Relacionado [Expresion regular para validar letras con acentos y ñ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81041/65), [Ayuda con una funcion que valida Letras - JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/127239/65)